Argue Uniqueness of Solutions
I'm trying to solve the following problem.

Let $f: \mathbb{R} \to \mathbb{R}$ locally Lipschitz function, and let $g: \mathbb{R} \to \mathbb{R}$ be a continuous function. Justify that the differential equation
$$x' = f(x) , y' = g(x)y$$
has the property of uniqueness of solutions.

The property of uniqueness of solutions means that given an initial condition $(t_0, x_0,y_0) \in \mathbb{R}^3$, if $\gamma_1: I_1 \to \mathbb{R}^2$ and $\gamma_2: I_2 \to \mathbb{R}^2$ are solutions of the ODE such that $t_0 \in I_1 \cap I_2$ with $\gamma_1(t_0) = \gamma_2(t_0) = (x_0,y_0)$ then for all $t \in I_1 \cap I_2$, we have $\gamma_1(t) = \gamma_2(t)$.
My approach was to analyze the equations separately. That is, given an initial condition $(t_0, x_0, y_0)$, for the first ODE
$$ x' = f(x),$$
we can apply the Picard Theorem directly, because $f$ is locally Lipschitz hence is continuous. So we have the property of uniqueness of solutions to that equation.
So given two solutions of the general EDO, say
$$ \gamma_1: I_1 \to \mathbb{R^2} \, : \, t \mapsto (\phi_1(t), \psi_1(t)), $$
$$ \gamma_2: I_2 \to \mathbb{R^2} \, : \, t \mapsto (\phi_2(t), \psi_2(t)), $$
with $\gamma_1(t_0) = \gamma_2(t_0) = (x_0, y_0)$. We must have for all $t \in I_1 \cap I_2$, that $\phi_1(t) = \phi_2(t)$.
If $y_0 \neq 0$ by the continuity of the solutions we can find a small neighborhood of $t_0$ still contained in the open interval $I_1 \cap I_2$, say $(t_0 - \delta, t_0 + \delta)$, such that $\psi_1(t), \psi_2(t) \neq 0$ for every $t \in (t_0 - \delta, t_0 + \delta)$. Hence for every such $t$,
$$ \frac{\psi_1'(t)}{\psi_1(t)} = g(\phi_1(t)) = g(\phi_2(t)) = \frac{\psi_2'(t)}{\psi_2(t)},$$
integrating,
$$ \int_{t_0}^t \frac{\psi_1'(s)}{\psi_1(s)} ds =  \log(\psi_1(t)) - \log(x_0) =  \log(\psi_2(t)) - \log(x_0) = \int_{t_0}^t \frac{\psi_2'(s)}{\psi_2(s)} ds.$$
Hence by logarithm is injective we have the equality
$$ \psi_1(t) = \psi_2(t) \, , \, \forall t \in (t_0 - \delta, t_0 + \delta).$$
But how do I argue for the other points on the interval $I_1 \cap I_2$? And if $y_0 = 0$?

Given the solution of $x' = f(x)$, which is a continuous function, the function $G(x,y) = g(x) y$ is continuous in $x$ and locally Lipschitz in $y$, with a Lipschitz constant $|g(x)|$ which is locally bounded as a function of $x$, so the differential equation $y' = G(x,y)$ satisfies the hypotheses of the Picard-Lindelöf existence and uniqueness theorem.
